# How to return an element that was detached ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a button element to appear in order to offer a "start again" option when the user loses in a game. `.detach()` works perfectly for keeping the button hidden, but I can't seem to get it to un-detach itself. Some answers have suggested to use the `append()` method but it doesn't work for me. Here is the code in which I try to `.detach()` the element and then `append()` it back.

```
  var detached_playAgainButton = $(".playAgainButton").detach();
  $("playAgainButton").append(detached_PlayAgainButton);
```

Comment: What if you just _hide_ the button instead of detaching it?

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the jQuery object in a variable then call `detach` on that variable, that way, the variable will hold the jQuery object containing the elements:

```
var detached_playAgainButton = $(".playAgainButton");

detached_playAgainButton.detach();

$("playAgainButton").append(detached_PlayAgainButton);
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ BTW are you sure about this selector? This should be the container of the detached element not the element itself
```